# Compass shows as compiling, but no changes to the site or the style.css

Tags: wordpress, sass, zurb-foundation, compass

I am using Bluehost hosting for a WP site using a Foundation 5 theme called JointsWP, and have been using compass to try and compile the .scss styles. It shows as compiling and initially made a few changes in relation to the body styles of the site, but once I started to modify the header styles, it seemed to no longer work. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the gems, downgrading to lower versions of both Sass and Compass, and I can't get it to work.

Comment: I also have tried backing up the config.rb and messing around with it to see if the configuration wasn't right... Again no dice.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are attempting to compile Sass on a server - this won't be possible. When working with Sass you need to work locally and then push your updates to the server.

Comment: I tried compiling the code locally and then pushing it to the server... which didn't work... and I tried doing it server side, which also didn't work. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Are other Sass files working or is the error specific to JointsWP?